# .Net Core Unit Testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, xunit.net

I have a web api as below, which is being called from my angularjs UI.

```
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    private static string dynamoDbTable = string.Empty;
    private readonly IDynamoDbManager<MyModel> _dynamoDbManager;

    public ValuesController(IOptions<Dictionary<string, string>> appSettings, IDynamoDbManager<MyModel> dynamoDbManager)
    {
        var vals = appSettings.Value;
        dynamoDbTable = vals["dynamoDbTable"];
        _dynamoDbManager = dynamoDbManager;
    }

[HttpGet("api/data")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllData(string status, string role)
{
    List<ScanCondition> conditions = new List<ScanCondition>();
    conditions.Add(new ScanCondition("status", ScanOperator.Contains, status));
    conditions.Add(new ScanCondition("role", ScanOperator.Contains, role));

    List<MyModel> model = new List<MyModel>();
    model = await _dynamoDbManager.GetAsync(conditions);            

    return Ok(model);
}

[HttpPost("api/save")]
public async Task<IActionResult> SaveData([FromBody] List<MyModel> listData, string input, string name, string type)
{
    List<MyModel> model = new List<MyModel>();
    foreach (var data in listData)
    {
        //populating data here and saving
         await _dynamoDbManager.SaveAsync(data);
    }
    return Ok();
}
}
```

}

Now I want to write test cases for my API endpoints. I have not written any unit test case before so need input in that. I have read basic documentation of xunit here.

Here is my sample test method:

```
public class ValuesControllerTests
{
    private Mock<IDynamoDbManager<MyModel>> _dbManager;
    private ValuesController _valueController;

    public ValuesControllerTests()
    {
        var mockRepository = new MockRepository(MockBehavior.Loose);
        _dbManager = mockRepository.Create<IDynamoDbManager<MyModel>>();
        var options = new OptionsWrapper<Dictionary<string, string>>(new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            {"dynamoDbTable", nameof(MyModel) }
        });
        _valueController = new ValuesController(options, _dbManager.Object);
    }

[Fact]
public async Task GetAllData_Test()
{
    var searchResult = new List<MyModel>()
    {
        new MyModel(){ }
    };

     //Here I am trying to use MOQ but this is not working fine
    _dbManager
     .Setup(_ => _.GetAsync(It.IsAny<List<ScanCondition>>()))
     .ReturnsAsync(searchResult);

    var result = _valueController.GetAllData("new", "admin");
    Assert.IsType<OkObjectResult>(result.Result);            
} 
}
 }
```

Can I test my method without using moq, if so how can I do so? Because with moq I am not able to test.
Secondly above test case I am just checking if api method returns OK. What other test cases can I write for my get and save method.

I have also created a git project in case anyone wants to look at project: https://github.com/kj1981/xunit

Would appreciate if someone can help me in this.

--Added--

I also tried one test as below, but is this fine? May be my thinking is wrong, with the below test I thought it would fail but it does not.

```
     [Fact]
    public async Task GetAllData_Test()
    {
        var searchResult = new List<MyModel>()
        {
            new MyModel(){ Id ="1", Name = "Adam", Role = "User", Status ="old" },
            new MyModel(){ Id ="2", Name = "Gary", Role = "Admin", Status ="new" }
        };

        _dbManager
         .Setup(_ => _.GetAsync(It.IsAny<List<ScanCondition>>()))
         .ReturnsAsync(searchResult);

        var okResult = _valueController.GetAllData("fail", "none").Result as OkObjectResult; ;
        var items = Assert.IsType<List<MyModel>>(okResult.Value);
        Assert.Equal(2, items.Count);
    }
```

Anyone with inputs ?

Comment: Could you give some specifics on how the unit test is behaving? Is it giving a compiler error or a test failure, and what is the message?

Comment: Where are you defining the variable `_valueController`? Where are you passing your `_dbManager` mock to the constructor of your controller?

Comment: I have updated my post with the entire code. Just FYI my api runs fine and returns all data from my dynamo db. I am just not sure how and what unit test to write.

Comment: @DanielMann Any inputs on above code?